# Toggle visibility of a form element

Tags: jquery, css, visibility, show-hide, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of a form element using jQuery. I have a flipswitch widget and am setting it's class with either the `class='reviewControls'` or `data-wrapper-class='reviewControls'` attributes, as can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znw67k79/1/). The problem is that it's working in the fiddle, but not in my code. My code hides the `<label>` field but not the `<input>` field. I'm finding it hard to debug as jQuery adds `style="display: none;` to the `<label>` element but leaves the `<input>` element (and it's styles) unchanged. Any ideas?

Comment: you should checked your codes because as you said its working on the fiddle there just might be some conflicts on your codes try and check them  thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks @RaniMorelesRubillos, in the web inspector (in Safari) it doesn't show the `reviewControls` style being added to either element; but rather it just adds `style="display: none;` to the `<label>` element itself (as opposed to the stylesheet) and doesn't add it to the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't seem to solve this problem, but wrapping the element in another `<div>` and then hiding that new `<div>` solved the problem.